# HTTP Not receiving JSON payload

Tags: mule

Using postman, I am posting a JSON message to mule,  the HTTP receiver inside mule flow is returning  the payload  org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@ format..

I tried to convert the payload into JSON using "Byte Array to Object" and then "Object to JSON", but I get the payload with lot of new line character

{\n \"Name\": \"John\",\n \"Code\": \"003\"\n}\n \n \t\n "

when I tried to extract the fields Name and code, receiving null

I am expecting the  payload as

{ 
"Name": "John", "Code": "003"

}

Is there something I am missing in the flow?

This must be a common problem, what is the standard way to receive JSON message inside mule flow?

Thank you

Comment: It ideally works the way you are doing.You can optionally use "Transform Message" to get customized output.Kindly paste your code so we can help you precisely.

Comment: use Object to string instead of "Byte Array to Object"

Comment: problem solve. Used transform  <dw:transform-message doc:name="transformMessage">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>,   now I can access the fields using #[payload.field],

Comment: `org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream` is not a format but the underlying representation of the data. If the POSTMAN request features a JSON `Content-Type` header then you should be able to access fields using the transform component.

Answer (score 0):

problem solve. Used transform

### %output application/java

payload]]>
        ,   now I can access the fields using #[payload.field],